# FreeNAS 9.3 doesn't see hard drive with previous FreeNAS installation

Tags: shell, freebsd, nas

So, I made a mistake and installed FreeNAS on the HDD on the server (this is a home share). I made a USB bootable media and installed it on the server.

After reading docs I realized I needed to install it on a USB media. I did that successfully, and I boot my computer with FreeNAS USB storage, 16GB.

Now when I go to GUI, it doesn't show the hard disk I have on the machine, all it shows is da0 -15 GB.

This is what I see from gpart show:

```
[root@freenas ~]# gpart show                                                    
=>      34  30277565  da0  GPT  (14G)                                           
        34      8190       - free -  (4M)                                       
      8224      1024    1  bios-boot  (512k)                                    
      9248  30268344    2  freebsd-zfs  (14G)                                   
  30277592         7       - free -  (3.5k)                                     

=>       34  625142381  ada0  GPT  (298G)                                       
         34       1024     1  bios-boot  (512k)                                 
       1058          6        - free -  (3.0k)                                  
       1064  625141344     2  freebsd-zfs  (298G)                               
  625142408          7     3  freebsd-ufs  (3.5k)
```

How to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it:

```
sysctl kern.geom.debugflags=0x10
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ada4 bs=512 count=1 && dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/ada5 bs=512 count=1
```

Forgot to reboot afterwards, thats why it didn't show in disks, now all ok.